# Is there any way to detect microphone is internal or external in flutter?

Tags: flutter, microphone

Is there any way to detect microphone is internal or external in flutter? I tried different packages and plugin but none of works! external microphone is when user plugged microhone or with earphone or headset mic.

Comment: put all packages you tried and describe what is a "external microphone"

Comment: @lakscastro external mic is earphone or headset mic or direct microphone via usb when user plugged and internal mic is system mic